# C++ cin/coutSegmentation Fault for integer or float vaiable but is ok for char type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

There is a Segmentation Fault on line `cin >> num;` for integer type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Hello World\n");

    cin >> num; // seg fault line

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Figure. Error for integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aap42.jpg)

While the char type runs fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    char str;

    printf("Hello World\n");

    cin >> str;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Figure. Fine for char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xbG8.jpg)

I'm using VSCode and MinGW, the c_cpp_properties.json is as follow:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Unless your standard library implemention has a bug or I'm missing something obvious there can't be a segmentation fault in this code. Is this the real code were you got the error or did you remove something important?

Comment: Thanks for the proof. That's nothing that should happen. Can you _reliably_ reproduce this error? When you remove all build artifacts, rebuild the first code from scratch and run it, does the error still appear? Sometimes compiler or debugger have their hickups, maybe you debugged an old executable, or something else.

Comment: A *"segmentation fault"* is nothing the Windows OS or Microsoft's compiler produce. What compiler and which C++ Standard Library implementation are you using?

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your information. I updated the MinGW from version 6 to version 8 and the problem was fixed.